# Ubuntu Won't Boot After 12.04 Upgrade, Timidity++ Error

Tags: installation, boot, upgrade, 12.04, midi

So I upgraded to 12.04 this afternoon from 11.10. However when I boot into Ubuntu, after the loading screen has hung for about 15 seconds, it then disappears and a black screen appears and appears to stall at the action 'timidity++ alsa midi emulation     [OK]'.

I've looked it up for a while now and there has been a few reports of it but no one seems to ever come to a solution and ends up doing a fresh install. This isn't an option for me.

It's clearly a Timidity error so even if I could temporarily bypass this and uninstall it, that'd be great.

Comment: Hey, you are wrong. The message you see states that starting Timidity was the last successful thing that your system did - so Timidity causes no problem here, it works okay - the problem is in whatever your system does NEXT, which seems to stop it (maybe it's Xorg failing to start?)

Comment: Yeah I soon realised that. Unfortunately no one was replying and I couldn't find any answer online so I had to go ahead and restart. I wouldn't consider this solved so I'm not going to mark it as so. Hopefully if anyone comes up with a answer they'll post it here for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

)

I got the same problem on my Notebook. I tried to boot into recovery to remove the package manually with dpkg -r timidity-daemon.  It doesnt work for me because dpkg reports an error two for an package (lexmark-driver). Perhaps it  works for you ...

Comment: I tried that and the same error. I'm guessing it hasn't actually got anything to do with Timidity then and more to do with the boot process.